# Multiple Select in Select2 for VueJS. Sometimes return blank selected

Tags: vuejs2, jquery-select2

Here `Select2.vue` comp source: https://pastebin.com/zKvaaDS9

Here `ItemDetail.vue` page source: https://pastebin.com/gL7a75hH

I use select2 in VueJS, which I created based on VueJS documentation and other resource. Everything seems work fine. But, sometimes `tag` or `selected` is not selecting correct which after I debug I found it sometimes `undefined`, `[]`, or `''`(empty).

I highly suspect this because async. Here what I want to archive: I want to show all units that support an item.

1. AJAX: api for get units
2. AJAX: api for get an item detail. Data item, include current units that support for this item.
3. Load select2 units based on `item.units` and `units`. Sometimes is workfine but sometimes is not.

Here some explaination what I do

```
// Calling item detail(ASYNC)
// api/item/detail/:id
var item = getItemDetail()

// Calling ajax units(ASYNC)
// api/category?group_by=units
var units = getUnits();
```

Hopely would arrange select2 `type=tags` would render correctly based on item.units(for v-model) and units for available in dropdown menu.

It seems not render correctly when:

1. Select2 render without options and value(ajax not complete for `item` and `units`)
2. AJAX Item finish first
3. AJAX Units finish last

When I debug, it seems select2 `updated` v-model with empty value because nothing match in select items with v-model value. So for example:

```
item.units = [1,2,3];
units = []; // Because not ready yet

$(this.$el).val(); // Return empty array or something
```

I tried correct the order something like this:

1. Select2 render without options and value(ajax not complete for `item` and `units`)
2. AJAX Units finish last, wait until finish and go to step 3
3. AJAX Item finish first

This work perfectly.

The question is: **Is it possible to run async and render select2 perfectly without thinking about ajax order or wait to complate first?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this in two ways.

1. You could store the value in a separate property of your select2 wrapper component, when the options changed, make sure to reapply your value to select2. This way, even if select2 sets value to empty, you will reset the original value after ajax finishes loading.
2. When the value changes and select 2 have no options loaded, create one option just so it won't set the value to empty. When your options finish loading, it will replace all items from select2 with ajax loaded ones.

```js
// Option 2: this would go inside Watch for value property
// Note that this works for a single select, for tags, the idea is the same 
// but you will have to create all the tags.
const select = $(this.$refs.select2);
if (select.find(`option[value="${value}"]`).length === 0) {
        select.append(
          $("<option>")
            .val(value)
            .text(this.displayText || "")
        );
      }
```

I've used option 2 at work (sorry, can't share the full code) and it worked. If it is unclear for you with just the snipped above, I can try and provide more details.

Comment: I got the idea. I read in select2 documentation too, but haven't tried yet. // I did similar thing with computed property (look at my select2 code). But some how didn't work properly. It seems that when `this.value` is undefined something not right happen.